# Is there a way to replace a dataframe in a named list in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out a way to replace a dataframe within a list because I eventually want to write a conditional statement where the user of a Shiny app can select which data they want to see when they export to an Excel file.

So how can I update the code below to where "my_list" will have "project_tibble_1" replaced with "project_tibble_2"?

Thank you.

```
library(tidyverse)


description_tibble <- tibble(
  Project_Description = c("Commerical", "Residential")
)


# Create a tibble with two columns: Project_Name and Project_Cost
project_tibble_1 <- tibble(
  Project_Name = paste("Project", 1:10),  # Generating project names
  Project_Cost = c(5, 7, -2, -8, 10, -3, 0, 6, -5, 4)  # Specifying the project costs
)


project_tibble_2 <- tibble(
  Project_Name = paste("Project", 11:20),  # Generating project names
  Project_Cost = c(5, 7, -2, -8, 10, -3, 0, 6, -5, 4)  # Specifying the project costs
)

my_list <- list("Project_Purpose" = description_tibble, "Project_Summary" =  project_tibble_1)
```

Comment: `my_list['Project_Summary'] <- project_tibble_2`?

Comment: @jay.sf close, but the RHS needs to be `list(project_tibble_2)`

Comment: @r2evans Right, missed double brackets, `my_list[['Project_Summary']] <- project_tibble_2`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter that you want to replace a frame with a frame, it's that `my_list` is a list, and a list with `[<-` (list-assignment) expects a list on the RHS of the equation as well.

```r
str(my_list)
# List of 2
#  $ Project_Purpose: tibble [2 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#   ..$ Project_Description: chr [1:2] "Commerical" "Residential"
#  $ Project_Summary: tibble [10 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#   ..$ Project_Name: chr [1:10] "Project 1" "Project 2" "Project 3" "Project 4" ...
#   ..$ Project_Cost: num [1:10] 5 7 -2 -8 10 -3 0 6 -5 4
my_list["Project_Summary"] <- list(project_tibble_2)
str(my_list)
# List of 2
#  $ Project_Purpose: tibble [2 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#   ..$ Project_Description: chr [1:2] "Commerical" "Residential"
#  $ Project_Summary: tibble [10 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#   ..$ Project_Name: chr [1:10] "Project 11" "Project 12" "Project 13" "Project 14" ...
#   ..$ Project_Cost: num [1:10] 5 7 -2 -8 10 -3 0 6 -5 4
```

@jay.sf's comment is quite appropriate: in the reassignment using `[`, you need to account for the same length on both sides. For instance, with

```r
other_list <- list(c(1:2), 3:4, 5:6)

### works because R recycles R to both elements
other_list[1:2] <- list(99)
other_list
# [[1]]
# [1] 99
# [[2]]
# [1] 99
# [[3]]
# [1] 5 6

### works because lengt(LHS) == length(RHS)
other_list[1:2] <- list(99, 98)

### fail
other_list[1:2] <- list(99, 98, 97)
# Warning in other_list[1:2] <- list(99, 98, 97) :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
other_list[1:3] <- list(99, 98)
# Warning in other_list[1:3] <- list(99, 98) :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: Note, that `is.list(project_tibble_2) == TRUE`. Maybe adapt explanation that we need something with same length as `length(my_list["Project_Summary"])`, Or better use `my_list[['Project_Summary']] <- project_tibble_2` to avoid extra listing.